# A non well formed numeric value encountered in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

Everything is working fine but after installation of auth package in laravel 8, and after logging into
that website "A non well formed numeric value encountered" error occured in every view. I can't find where is the problem. I also updated from command "composer update" but still error is there.

[This is The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7SXD.png)

I need it's answer to reslove this issue.
Below is the Controller Code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Image;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\state;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FrontController extends Controller
{
    public function homePage()
    {
        $popular = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(8)->get();
        $latest = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(4)->get();
        $img = Image::get();
        $imgs = Image::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();

        $pimage = [];
        foreach ($img as $image) {
            if (!isset($pimage[$image->product_id]))
                $pimage[$image->product_id] = $image->image;
        }

        $pimages = [];
        foreach ($imgs as $images) {
            if (!isset($pimages[$images->product_id]))
                $pimages[$images->product_id] = $images->image;
        }
        $cartCount = 0;
        if(Auth::check()){
            $cartItems = Cart::join('products','carts.product_id','=','products.id')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
            $cartCount = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();

            return view('pages.index', compact('popular','latest','pimage','pimages','img','cartItems','cartCount', 'categories'));
        }
        else
            return view('pages.index', compact('popular','latest','pimage','pimages','img','cartCount', 'categories'));
    }

    public function ProductDetail($slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        $images = Image::where('product_id',$product->id)->get();
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();
        $cartCount = 0;

        if(Auth::check()){
            $cartItems = Cart::join('products','carts.product_id','=','products.id')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
            $cartCount = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
            return view('pages.product_detail', compact('product','images','cartCount','cartItems','categories'));
        }
        else
            return view('pages.product_detail', compact('product','images','cartCount','categories'));
    }

    public function CartDetail()
    {
        $img = Image::get();
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();
        $pimage = [];
        foreach ($img as $image) {
            if (!isset($pimage[$image->product_id]))
                $pimage[$image->product_id] = $image->image;
        }
        $cartItems = Cart::join('products','carts.product_id','=','products.id')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
        $cartCount = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
        return view('pages.cart', compact('cartCount','cartItems','pimage','categories'));
    }

    public function Checkout()
    {
        $img = Image::get();
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id',0)->get();
        $pimage = [];
        foreach ($img as $image) {
            if (!isset($pimage[$image->product_id]))
                $pimage[$image->product_id] = $image->image;
        }

        $state = state::where('country_id',101)->get();

        $cartItems = Cart::join('products','carts.product_id','=','products.id')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
        $cartCount = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
        return view('pages.checkout', compact('cartCount','cartItems','pimage','state','categories'));
    }
}
```

Comment: go to storage/logs/laravel.log and copy/paste the error including the entire stacktrace to your original question

Comment: @UnderDog See Now.

Comment: Ok, there's an error above this error you copy/pasted from the laravel.log, copy/paste that one as well. There is a controller, that 'sends' this view. Open the controller action and copy/paste that one as well in your original question

Comment: Everything is working fine until i login to this website. whenever i login this error occured on every single route of frontend

Comment: Issue Is Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how without this code on every line of Cart::join, "select('carts.*','product_name')->" the error occured but when i inserted this select statment on specific columns then issue is gets resolved.